# ArcGIS Mobile projects access from Field device

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-mobile

I am trying to figure out how to allow field users to connect to ArcGIS Server based mobile services within an enterprise environment. As part of this, I am asking network security to allow this access from [Trimble GPS](http://www.trimble.com/mappingGIS/) units. We are going to be doing this for the first time and data sensitivity is an issue. I am looking for some feedback from other users with similar experience within enterprise environment.

I know that I need to allow access to mobile projects but I am curious if there is any other access that we need to provide. I want to have as much detail as possible for network security team.
*http://ArcGIS/Mobile/Content/WindowsMobile/Projects

Appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: https with 128 bit encryption - http://www.inet2000.com/public/encryption.htm will be secure enough with user/password access on the ArcGIS Server side.

Comment: If the Comment from @Mapperz were made into an Answer would you be happy to Accept it?